# How can I keep my org repo updated with the main repo?

Tags: git

We follow the below distributed source code management practice.

We have a main repo which contains all the live code. And all the teams are supposed to create a fork to their respective git orgs and do their feature specific work on the org repo. The problem we face is that , before raising a pull request we will need to rebase the org repo to the HEAD of main repo. This is very tedious process( all those merge conflicts :-/ ). I want to know if there is some way in which I can automate this process. Using which I can rebase my repo develop branch to the latest main repo branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not aware of an automatic process to handle potential merge conflicts. But by following some rules, like the one described in the [gitworkflows manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitworkflows.html) you can reduce the number of potential merge conflicts.

A detailed strategy is described [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), with multiple branches to track feature, hotfix and release changes. This way you can merge the changes as soon as they are ready.
[image]